# Heroku SSL Endpoint for Wildcard certificate - adding staging env

Tags: ssl, heroku, dns, staging

I have a production application that is using a wildcard SSL certificate via Heroku's SSL endpoint - `bar.com`. The staging app doesn't have an SSL endpoint set up. Instead, I added it as a subdomain to `bar.com` as `foo.bar.com`. I am getting `Your connection is not private` error when I try to access my staging app via `https`. Should a separate SSL Endpoint get set up for the staging app? If so, how would I add it to my existing wildcard SSL?

Comment: The staging app will need it's own `SSL Endpoint` add-on. You can upload the same certificate (via `heroku certs:add ...`) to the staging app and it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wildcard certificate for *.bar.com. Will automatically secures unlimited number of 1st Level sub-domains under bar.com. The wildcard certificate already secures foo.bar.com in the certificate for *.bar.com. All you need to do it to simply install the wildcard certificate for *.bar.com on the server where foo.bar.com is hosted.

Comment: Turns out I had a misspelling in my DNS config =P.